# How to properly run database (rethinkdb) with docker-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I need help to run a database with docker and nodejs. I do not understand where I'm going wrong, but I can not make connection between my container with database and my container with node. This is the db link in docker: "https://hub.docker.com/_/rethinkdb/".Then follows:

**my Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:latest
ENV HOME=/src/jv-agricultor
RUN mkdir -p $HOME/
WORKDIR $HOME/
ADD package* $HOME/
RUN npm install
EXPOSE 80
ADD . $HOME/
CMD ["node", "node_modules/.bin/nodemon", "-L", "bin/www"]
```

**My docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3"
volumes:
  rethindb-data:
    external: true
services:
  db:
    image: rethinkdb:latest
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
      - "29015:29015"
      - "28015:28015"
  api:
    image: hello-nodemon
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development
      - PORT=80
      - DB_HOST=localhost
      - DB_PORT=28015
    deploy:
      # replicas: 5
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: "0.1"
          memory: 50M
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
    ports:
      - "3000:80"
    volumes:
      - .:/src/jv-agricultor
      - /src/jv-agricultor/node_modules
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks:
      - webnet
networks:
  webnet:
```

i run: *docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml webservice*

**My docker service**

```
ID                  NAME                MODE                REPLICAS            IMAGE                  PORTS
yez42a7w8khs        webservice_api      replicated          1/1                 hello-nodemon:latest   *:3000->80/tcp
n8idu78cp18m        webservice_db       replicated          1/1                 rethinkdb:latest       *:8080->8080/tcp,*:28015->28015/tcp,*:29015->29015/tcp
```

**My docker service api (here is node/express)**

```
ID                  NAME                IMAGE                  NODE                DESIRED STATE       CURRENT STATE            ERROR          PORTS
p20qdagcspjc        webservice_api.1    hello-nodemon:latest   abner               Running             Running 28 minutes ago
```

**My Docker service db**

```
ID                  NAME                IMAGE               NODE                DESIRED STATE       CURRENT STATE            ERROR       PORTS
3046xuo4l8ix        webservice_db.1     rethinkdb:latest    abner               Running             Running 30 minutes ago
```

**My logs internal db**

```
webservice_db.1.3046xuo4l8ix@abner    | Recursively removing directory /data/rethinkdb_data/tmp
webservice_db.1.3046xuo4l8ix@abner    | Initializing directory /data/rethinkdb_data
webservice_db.1.3046xuo4l8ix@abner    | Running rethinkdb 2.3.6~0jessie (GCC 4.9.2)...
webservice_db.1.3046xuo4l8ix@abner    | Running on Linux 4.15.0-24-generic x86_64
webservice_db.1.3046xuo4l8ix@abner    | Loading data from directory /data/rethinkdb_data
webservice_db.1.3046xuo4l8ix@abner    | Listening for intracluster connections on port 29015
webservice_db.1.3046xuo4l8ix@abner    | Listening for client driver connections on port 28015
webservice_db.1.3046xuo4l8ix@abner    | Listening for administrative HTTP connections on port 8080
webservice_db.1.3046xuo4l8ix@abner    | Listening on cluster addresses: 127.0.0.1, 172.18.0.3, 10.0.5.182, 10.0.5.183, 10.255.11.212, 10.255.11.213
webservice_db.1.3046xuo4l8ix@abner    | Listening on driver addresses: 127.0.0.1, 172.18.0.3, 10.0.5.182, 10.0.5.183, 10.255.11.212, 10.255.11.213
webservice_db.1.3046xuo4l8ix@abner    | Listening on http addresses: 127.0.0.1, 172.18.0.3, 10.0.5.182, 10.0.5.183, 10.255.11.212, 10.255.11.213
webservice_db.1.3046xuo4l8ix@abner    | Server ready, "069fd360acfb_jot" c1cf5173-cf0d-457f-9c8f-4ba1756c28d8
```

**my app.js**

```
...
var connect = require('./lib/connect');
console.log('DB_HOST: ' + process.env.DB_HOST);
console.log('DB_PORT: ' + process.env.DB_PORT);
console.log('PORT: ' + process.env.PORT);
console.log('NODE_ENV: ' + process.env.NODE_ENV);
...
```

**My connect middleware**

```
'use strict'

// import r from 'rethinkdb';
var r = require('rethinkdb');

module.exports._connect = (function _connect(req, res, next) {
    r.connect( {host: process.env.DB_HOST, port: process.env.DB_PORT}, (err, conn) => {
        console.log(err);
    })
})();
```

**My service docker api logs respose**

```
webservice_api.1.p20qdagcspjc@abner    | [nodemon] restarting due to changes...
webservice_api.1.p20qdagcspjc@abner    | [nodemon] starting `node bin/www`
webservice_api.1.p20qdagcspjc@abner    | DB_HOST: localhost
webservice_api.1.p20qdagcspjc@abner    | DB_PORT: 28015
webservice_api.1.p20qdagcspjc@abner    | PORT: 80
webservice_api.1.p20qdagcspjc@abner    | NODE_ENV: development
webservice_api.1.p20qdagcspjc@abner    | { ReqlDriverError: Could not connect to localhost:28015.
webservice_api.1.p20qdagcspjc@abner    | connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:28015
webservice_api.1.p20qdagcspjc@abner    |     at ReqlDriverError.ReqlError [as constructor] (/src/jv-agricultor/node_modules/rethinkdb/errors.js:23:13)
webservice_api.1.p20qdagcspjc@abner    |     at new ReqlDriverError (/src/jv-agricultor/node_modules/rethinkdb/errors.js:68:50)
webservice_api.1.p20qdagcspjc@abner    |     at TcpConnection.<anonymous> (/src/jv-agricultor/node_modules/rethinkdb/net.js:94:27)
webservice_api.1.p20qdagcspjc@abner    |     at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:273:13)
webservice_api.1.p20qdagcspjc@abner    |     at TcpConnection.emit (events.js:182:13)
webservice_api.1.p20qdagcspjc@abner    |     at Socket.<anonymous> (/src/jv-agricultor/node_modules/rethinkdb/net.js:705:22)
webservice_api.1.p20qdagcspjc@abner    |     at Socket.emit (events.js:187:15)
webservice_api.1.p20qdagcspjc@abner    |     at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:82:8)
webservice_api.1.p20qdagcspjc@abner    |     at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:50:3)
webservice_api.1.p20qdagcspjc@abner    |     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
webservice_api.1.p20qdagcspjc@abner    | From previous event:
webservice_api.1.p20qdagcspjc@abner    |     at Function.<anonymous> (/src/jv-agricultor/node_modules/rethinkdb/net.js:945:10)
webservice_api.1.p20qdagcspjc@abner    |     at Function.connect (/src/jv-agricultor/node_modules/rethinkdb/util.js:43:16)
webservice_api.1.p20qdagcspjc@abner    |     at _connect (/src/jv-agricultor/lib/connect.js:9:7)
webservice_api.1.p20qdagcspjc@abner    |     at Object.<anonymous> (/src/jv-agricultor/lib/connect.js:19:3)
webservice_api.1.p20qdagcspjc@abner    |     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
webservice_api.1.p20qdagcspjc@abner    |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
webservice_api.1.p20qdagcspjc@abner    |     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
webservice_api.1.p20qdagcspjc@abner    |     at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
webservice_api.1.p20qdagcspjc@abner    |     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
webservice_api.1.p20qdagcspjc@abner    |     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
webservice_api.1.p20qdagcspjc@abner    |     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
webservice_api.1.p20qdagcspjc@abner    |     at Object.<anonymous> (/src/jv-agricultor/app.js:14:15)
webservice_api.1.p20qdagcspjc@abner    |     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
webservice_api.1.p20qdagcspjc@abner    |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
webservice_api.1.p20qdagcspjc@abner    |     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
webservice_api.1.p20qdagcspjc@abner    |     at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
webservice_api.1.p20qdagcspjc@abner    |     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
webservice_api.1.p20qdagcspjc@abner    |     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
webservice_api.1.p20qdagcspjc@abner    |     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
webservice_api.1.p20qdagcspjc@abner    |   name: 'ReqlDriverError',
webservice_api.1.p20qdagcspjc@abner    |   msg:
webservice_api.1.p20qdagcspjc@abner    |    'Could not connect to localhost:28015.\nconnect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:28015',
webservice_api.1.p20qdagcspjc@abner    |   frames: undefined,
webservice_api.1.p20qdagcspjc@abner    |   message:
webservice_api.1.p20qdagcspjc@abner    |    'Could not connect to localhost:28015.\nconnect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:28015' }
```

Comment: What is the value of `process.env.DB_HOST` and other environmental variables in `r.connect( {host: process.env.DB_HOST,...`? Where is you middleware running?

Comment: Hello Alex Karshin, the environment variables are in docker-compose.yml. I'm importing the connect file into the app.js.

Comment: Could you please explain how `DB_HOST`, which is in environment of `db` container, gets into your `web` container? This really eludes me, I don't work with node though.

Comment: I have promoted some changes, but I have not gotten the answer yet, but see if it is clearer.The environment variables are in docker-compose.yml and are received by nodejs through process.env. I can see this in the logs I made on app.js.

Comment: I can access through my browser the database in localhost: 8080, this proves that it is working, but the container with my api (nojs, express) does not see my database. The environment variables pass correctly.

Comment: `I can access through my browser the database in localhost: 8080` -- of course you will. You are exposing ports to host. But connection between containers is something else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

spawnia has a point, but might not have the right answer. If you take a look at `docker ps -a` the name of your database container is `webservice_db`. Therefore, you will not be successful if you try to connect to rethinkdb on localhost (cuz obviously it's not on localhost).

You must either hardcode the container name (`webservice_db`) to your config file, or *do* set it in `docker-compose.yml`. But if you do, I suggest you set the container names explicitly:

```
version: "3"
...
services:
  db:
    container_name: webservice_db
    ...
  api:
    container_name: webservice_api
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development
      - PORT=80
      - DB_HOST= webservice_db
      - DB_PORT=28015
  ...
```

There, now it should work normally.

Comment: container_name: webservice_db not work in version 3, maybe work version 2. The correct answer was given by spawnia. I thank you very much for you willingness to help. Thank you very much :)

Comment: [your statement is incorrect](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#container_name). It works very well in version 3.

Comment: in my terminal: 
container_name: Setting the container name is not supported.
Creating service webservice_db
Creating service webservice_api

Comment: but work. Thanks. Sorry, I was too dumb not to test completely. Oddly it appeared that naming container was not supported, so I thought it would not work, but it worked very well.

Comment: @AlexKarshin Thanks for this.... spent a lot of time trying to figure it out why it wasnt working…

Answer (score 5):

`docker-compose` does inter-service communication by service name, so the value of `DB_HOST` should be `db`.

On a side note, unless you need to expose the database outside of the stack, you do not need the port mapping.

@Alex Karshin It is unnecessary to fully specify the container name. The first example in the [docker-compose networking docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) shows how simple it really is.

Comment: Thank you very much for  your help. This is worked very well :)

Comment: ale'x response was more complete. Thanks

Comment: I think that config files are better kept concise, so i do not see the benefit of naming the containers. It only serves a purpose if you want to interact with them from outside of the stack.